# Create a radio in a group voice chat on Telegram

Tags: telegram

**Attention: If this is not the Stack community for this type of question, please do not vote negative, please indicate in which Stack community I should ask that I delete the question without losing points.**

I am researching a way to use the voice chat of a Telegram group to become a radio, I want to know if by chance someone has any idea on how I could make this exist.

In this case, the idea would be to create an online radio on some website and somehow leave a Telegram profile just to play that radio in the voice chat.

Today I do this manually, leaving a speaker near the cell phone and it detects what is playing through the microphone, but the quality is very poor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several libraries available out there with which you could stream music in telegram voice chats such as [tgcalls](https://pypi.org/project/pytgcalls/), [pytgcalls](https://pypi.org/project/py-tgcalls/) in python
that can used along with [pyrogram](https://pypi.org/project/Pyrogram/).

Comment: Unfortunately all the options I've tested are audio quality equal to low quality microphone.  I believe that this will only improve in the future. By the way, thanks for the tip mate!